# setBackgroundColor() not working on view when checkbox is checked or button is pressed

Tags: java, android, colors, checkbox

I am attempting to make it so that whenever a checkbox is checked the view is one color and when it is unchecked it is another however when i check the box the view turns black and then nothing else happens when i check or uncheck the box.

**activity:**

```
package fsg.dev.test.checkboxtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class checkBoxTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
CheckBox checkbox;
SeekBar seekbar;
View view;
Button button;

private static final String TAG = "Checkbox Test";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            final String bool;
            if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                bool = "True";
                Log.d(TAG, bool);
                setBlue();
            } else {
                bool = "False";
                Log.d(TAG, bool);
                setDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    checkbox.toggle();
    view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Color);
}

private void setBlue(){
    Log.d(TAG, "In setBlue()");
    view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Color);
}

private void setDefault(){
    Log.d(TAG, "In setDefault()");
    view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Default);
}
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<CheckBox 
    android:text="Background Color" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:checked="false"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox">
</CheckBox>
<Button
    android:text="Background Color" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button">
</Button>
<SeekBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >
</SeekBar>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Default"
    android:id="@+id/background">
</View>
```

**manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="fsg.dev.test.checkboxtest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".checkBoxTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

can anyone figure out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get from the logcat? are the methods getting called as expected?

Comment: i get no warnings or errors from logcat and i know everything is being called as expected as i traced all the functions. i tried the answer below and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the method `setBlue()` and `setDefault()` , with : 
`YourActivity.this.setBlue()` and `YourActivity.this.setDefault();`

Note  : in the `view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yourColor)` ; replace it with : `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE) ;`

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response... it worked like a charm. though i did change `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue)` to `view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Color)` so that i could still use custom colors.